# Webscrape data with R

Tags: xml, web-scraping, rcurl, rvest

I am trying to scrape the data of the following page using rcurl but it doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to scrape the data from this page?

```
url = "http://www.gallop.co.za/#meeting#20170305#44"
fromJSON(url)
```

It comes back with error:

```
Error in feed_push_parser(readBin(con, raw(), n), reset = TRUE) : 
  lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang=en> 
                     (right here) ------^
```

How do i correctly scrape this page?

thanks,

Comment: are you sure you're reading a json file, as required by `fromJSON`? If so, test it on a site like http://jsonlint.com

Comment: No, i'm not convinced it is json - but how do i tell the difference and know which function to use?

Comment: Well if you look at the web site you included (e.g. open in Firefox, right click, "Inspect source") you will see that it says at the top of the document it says `<!DOCTYPE html>`. So you probably want to parse that with an HTML parser. [Here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/htmltotext-extracting-text-from-html-via-xpath/) is a tutorial that might help, I am personally not that familiar with web data in R.

Answer (score 0):

This url links to an html file, rather than json. Probably you need `getURL` function from `RCurl` package. You can analysis web data through firefox's firebug.